# How to filter out only fragmented files from the log?

Tags: logs, defragmentation

Supposing I have just finished a defragmentation on `ext4` file system on a HDD:

```
sudo e4defrag -v / > ~/defrag-2017-11-05 2>&1 &
```

Which is most probably unnecessary, but I wanted to see, which files have been fragmented.

The log looks like:

```
==> defrag-2017-11-05 <==
ext4 defragmentation for directory(/)
[1/403415] "/"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[2/403415] "/usr"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[3/403415] "/usr/share"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[4/403415] "/usr/share/ppp"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[5/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[5/403415]/usr/share/ppp/chap-secrets:    100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[6/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[6/403415]/usr/share/ppp/provider.chatscript: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[7/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[7/403415]/usr/share/ppp/provider.peer:   100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[8/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[8/403415]/usr/share/ppp/pap-secrets: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[9/403415] "/usr/share/backgrounds"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[10/403415] "/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[11/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[11/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/Gloria.jpg:    100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[12/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[12/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/aviatorjk_2441.jpg:    100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[13/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[13/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/theaeffect_3.png:  100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[14/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[14/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/multigons.jpg: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[15/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[15/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/Felicia.png:   100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[16/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[16/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/LinuxMint.png: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[17/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[17/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/air.jpg:   100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[18/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[18/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/curve.jpg: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[19/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[19/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/fizzy.jpg: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[20/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[20/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/silent_green.jpg:  100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[21/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[21/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/aviatorjk_2112.jpg:    100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[22/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[22/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/Emotion.jpg:   100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[23/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[23/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/pr09studio_spring.png: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[24/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[24/403415]/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-retro/Talento-1.jpg: 100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[324150/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[324150/403415]/home/ruzena/StaM-EM->enM-CM-)/Altitude.2017.DVDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO/Altitude.2017.DVDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.avi:   100%  extents: 20 -> 20 [ OK ]
[324290/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[324290/403415]/home/ruzena/StaM-EM->enM-CM-)/Savage.Dog.2017.BRRip.XviD.AC3-EVO/Savage.Dog.2017.BRRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.avi: 100%  extents: 20 -> 20 [ OK ]
[325184/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[325184/403415]/home/ruzena/StaM-EM->enM-CM-)/Death.Race.2050.2017.DVDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO/Death.Race.2050.2017.DVDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.avi: 100%  extents: 20 -> 20 [ OK ]
[325356/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[325356/403415]/home/ruzena/StaM-EM->enM-CM-)/Kong.Skull.Island.2017.TS.XviD.AC3-RUSSIAN.avi:    100%  extents: 20 -> 20 [ OK ]
[352147/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[352147/403415]/home/ruzena/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/d9b788060b0d42ce_0:     0%^[[79;0H^[[K[352147/403415]/home/ruzena/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/d9b788060b0d42ce_0:  100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[352943/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[352943/403415]/home/ruzena/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/d7789aeea4cbf251_1:     0%^[[79;0H^[[K[352943/403415]/home/ruzena/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/d7789aeea4cbf251_1:  100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[354676/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[354676/403415]/home/ruzena/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/98b71219db7f9992_1:     0%^[[79;0H^[[K[354676/403415]/home/ruzena/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/98b71219db7f9992_1:  100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[400977/403415]^[[79;0H^[[K[400977/403415]/home/ruzena/.local/share/zeitgeist/fts.index/postlist.DB:      0%^[[79;0H^[[K[400977/403415]/home/ruzena/.local/share/zeitgeist/fts.index/postlist.DB:   100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
```

Since I don't have any experience with `awk` and similar tools, I wonder:

How to filter out only fragmented files from the log? If even possible...

For specialists: If you could sort it by the most fragmented files, that would be awesome, but not a condition to answer this question.

A line I don't want to see end in:

```
... extents: 1 -> 1 [ OK ]
```

Lines I want to see end in:

```
... extents: 5 -> 1 [ OK ]
...  extents: 20 -> 5   [ OK ]
```

Where I need to show only lines with `5` or whatever number there is on that very place, higher than 1 obviously.

---

**EDIT:**

Example output of the verbose defragmentation for you to try the commands on:

https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/public/linux/defrag-2017-11-05.bz2

Just extract it and you're good to go.

Comment: Can you give an example of a line you want and a line you dont want?

Comment: So you only want line with a changing number here: `20 -> 5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{ if ($4!=$6) print $4 - $6" "$0_}' ~/defrag-2017-11-05 | sort -g
```

We use awk to compare the two columns in the input to see if they are not equal and print out the difference in values followed by the whole lines. Then we sort the filtered lines by the differences that we added at the start of the line.

If you want to check for lines with the first number higher than 1 you can use

```
awk '{ if ($4>1) print $0_}' ~/defrag-2017-11-05 | sort -gk4
```

Here we simply sort on the 4th column instead of creating a new difference column.

#### Edit

To handle spaces in filenames and weird characters at the start of lines and to filter out other lines use

```
awk '/extents: / { sub(/.*\]\//, "/"); sub(/:/, "", $1); if ($(NF-5)!=$(NF-3)) print $(NF-5) - $(NF-3)" "$1 }' ~/defrag-2017-11-05 | sort -g
```

Here is the awk script formatted nicely to make it easier to read

```
/extents: / { 
  sub(/.*\]\//, "/");
  sub(/:/, "", $1);
  if ($(NF-5)!=$(NF-3)) print $(NF-5) - $(NF-3)" "$1
}
```

1. filters out any line that does not have `extents:` in it.
2. replaces the starting characters up to `]/` with `/` to strip the nonsense at the start of the lines.
3. removes `:` from the filename to make it a bit cleaner
4. compares the two fields we care about counting from the end of the string and prints out the lines where the two numbers differ with this difference.

Comment: It does not work because there are control character in the output - which will change the regex I used. There are also lines that we do not want in the input which should be filtered out. This is why you need to give full examples when you ask the question.

Comment: So you did not do the file redirection like in your question? Most programs stripe color control codes when you redirect the output. Which again, will change the answer to the question.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin Note with awk you can also count back from the last field to get the field you want, to avoid complications when there may be spaces in the input line. E.g. `$(NF-5)` for the number before the `->`.